# Biholomorphism between two strips

Tags: complex-analysis

Is every open infinite strip $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$ biholomorphic to $S=\{z : |\mbox{Re}(z)| \leq \pi/2 \}$?. Is there a homemorphism $\overline{A} \to \overline{S}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Riemann Mapping Theorem. Actually, just rotate and stretch.

Comment: Is there problem with the boundaries?